# Get file path from Uri showing exception in android 10

Tags: android, kotlin

this is my code to get a real file path from Uri. It is working fine below all devices except Android 10. Please help me out. Thanks in Advance

```
enter code here
```

fun getPathFromUri(
        context: Conte`enter code here`xt,
        Uri: Uri
    ): String? {
        val isKitKat: Boolean = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

```
    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            val docId: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {

                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + split[1]
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            val id: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                java.lang.Long.valueOf(id)
            )
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            val docId: String = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(":").toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            var contentUri: Uri? = null
            if ("image" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("video" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if ("audio" == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            val selection = "_id=?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                split[1]
            )
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
        }
    } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {

        // Return the remote address
        return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(
            context,
            uri,
            null,
            null
        )
    } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return uri.path
    }
    return null
}

fun getDataColumn(
    context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?,
    selectionArgs: Array<String>?
): String? {
    var cursor: Cursor? = null
    val column = "_data"
    val projection = arrayOf(
        column
    )
    try {
        cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
            null
        )
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val index: Int = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
            return cursor.getString(index)
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) cursor.close()
    }
    return null
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param Uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param Uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
}

/**
 * @param Uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: "It is working fine below all devices except Android 10" -- no, it is not.

Comment: have the same issue. File.list() returns Null. quite worried since my app does cleanup work where it deletes old images to keep storage light. Is there an alternative in Android 10 to get list of files in a directory?